# Proof verification: functions equal on rationals are equal on reals

Tags: real-analysis, functions, solution-verification, proof-explanation

Problem. Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be two continuous functions in $\mathbb{R}$ and such that for all $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ it is $f(x)=g(x)$.

Prove that then $f=g$.

*After writing this solution, I've seen the textbook's one and seen that this can be easily proved by contradiction, but I would like to confirm if my reasoning is valid as well.*

My try: Let $\epsilon>0$ and let $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

By hypothesis $f$ and $g$ are continuous in $\mathbb{R}$, hence for all $x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$ there exists $\delta_1>0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta_1 \implies |f(x)-f(x_0)|<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$.

Similarly, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ there exists $\delta_2>0$ such that $|x-x_0|<\delta_2 \implies |g(x)-g(x_0)|<\frac{1}{2}\epsilon$.

Since $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$, this means that for all $\sigma>0$ and for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ exists $q \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $|x-q|<\sigma$.

Let $\delta=\text{min}\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$: since $\sigma>0$ is arbitrary, using the definition of density with $\sigma<\delta$ means that $|x-q|<\sigma<\delta \implies |x-q|<\delta$ and so, using the definition of continuity with $q$ instead of $x_0$ I get that

$$|f(x)-g(x)|=|f(x)-f(q)+f(q)-g(q)+g(q)-g(x)|$$

$$\leq |f(x)-f(q)|+|g(x)-g(q)|+|f(p)-g(q)| < \epsilon+|f(q)-g(q)|$$

But by hypothesis $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $q \in \mathbb{Q}$, hence $|f(q)-g(q)|=0$ and so it is $|x-q|<\delta \implies |f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$.

Since $x\in\mathbb{R}$ is arbitrary, this holds for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$; since this holds for all $\epsilon>0$, it is $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$, meaning $f=g$.

I am not sure if this is correct, mainly because I deduce that when I deduce that $|f(x)-g(x)|<\epsilon$ only when $|x-q|<\delta$; I have this feeling that this doesn't prove what I want, because the implication is valid only in a neighborhood of $x$. However, my guess is that this could be correct because $x$ is arbitrary (so this can be repeated for any $x$ obtaining the result everywhere) and because I assume that I can always satisfy the condition $|x-q|<\delta$ by the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ in $\mathbb{R}$, hence even if the equality holds only if "$x$ and $q$ are near" I can always make them near and so this works. Am I guessing correctly or this proof doesn't work?

Comment: Okay..... key point.  If $|a-b| < \epsilon$ for *all* $\epsilon > 0$ then $a=b$.  Nothing to do with functions.  Alternatively:  If $a +\epsilon > b$ for all $\epsilon> 0$ then $a \ge b$ and $a < b$ is impossible.  This are *useful* analytical tools.  Pf:.  If $a\ne b$ then $|b-a| > 0$.  So if we have $\epsilon =|b-a|$ we get the contradictory $|b-a|<|b-a|$.

Comment: Is your concern that you only proven $f(x) = g(x)$ for the values of $x$ where $x$ is in a neighborhood of $x$?  That is not an issue.  $x$ is *always* in every neighborhood of $x$ so $f(x)=g(x)$ for any one arbitrary $x$. And as it is true for any arbitrary $x$ it is true for all $x$.... Or is your concerned that you only proved $|f(x)-g(x)| < \epsilon$ but not $f(x)=g(x)$?  That is also not an issue.  If $0\le |a-b| < \epsilon$ for *all* $\epsilon > 0$ then $|a-b|=0$ and $a = b$.

Comment: It’s probably easier to note that if $f, g$ are continuous, then so is $h=f-g$.  Then work with $h$, which you know to be $0$ at all rationals and prove it must be identically $0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a valid proof, but I think it's presented a little sloppily, which is accounting for your lack of faith in it. You created these $\delta_1$ and $\delta_2$, exactly as you should, depending on $\varepsilon > 0$. You should then define $\delta = \min \{\delta_1, \delta_2\} > 0$, then say

> By the density of $\Bbb{Q}$ in $\Bbb{R}$, there exists some $q \in \Bbb{Q}$ such that $|x - q| < \delta$. Let $q$ be such a rational number.

There's no need to bring in $\sigma$, just fix some such $q$ (which depends on $x$ and $\varepsilon > 0$). Using this fixed $q$, you can follow your argument to conclude that $|f(x) - g(x)| < \varepsilon$. This conclusion holds true, regardless of the choice of $q$ (so long as it satisfies $|x - q| < \delta$ and is rational), so there's no need to present the conclusion as
$$|x - q| < \delta \implies |f(x) - g(x)| < \varepsilon.$$
In this context, $q$ is fixed, so the premise is trivially satisfied. There's no need to include it. Such a $q$ exists, and the conclusion doesn't depend on which $q$ is chosen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I assume you mean that I must use the arbitrarity of $σ>0$ only after fixing $δ =\min \{δ_1,δ_2\}$, because I want it to be lesser than the quantity $δ$ needed to be sure that the premise $|x−q|<\delta$ of the implication $|x−q|<δ⟹|f(x)−g(x)|<ϵ$ true. Doing this, I am sure the conclusion hold (because the premise is true) and so there is no need to worry about the possibility of "$x$ being near $q$" or not as I was, because density assures that it always holds in this situation. Is this correct?

Comment: You don't need an intermediary quantity. If $|x - q| < \min\{\delta_1, \delta_2\}$, then $|x - q| < \delta_1$ and $|x - q| < \delta_2$, which leads to the desired conclusions about $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ being close to $f(q)$ and $g(q)$ respectively. And yes, you don't need to worry about $x$ being near $q$, because you're basically defining $q$ to be sufficiently near $x$.